# Updating multiple progress bars from multiple tasks in task list using IProgress<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have multiple tasks that will be running in parallel. They are gathered in a list of tasks. Each task has a progress bar associated with it. I've been trying to implement the IProgress API in order to update the progress bars while the task runs. However, the progress bar only updates when the task is completed.

I have a set of test code that simulates my problem, and no matter how I modify it, the task bars only update when the task is completed.

As each task is created, I pass Progress object that will update the right progress bar. This Progress object is passed to the inner task to be updated with each loop. The Progress.Report() method will check for an InvokeRequired, although I don't think this should be necessary if you're using the IProgress API with asynchronous methods.

I've included the code. The form simply has a button (button1) that starts all the processes, and there are 11 progress bars that should update with each task.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ProgressBar> listOfProgressBars = new List<ProgressBar>
            {
                progressBar1,
                progressBar2,
                progressBar3,
                progressBar4,
                progressBar5,
                progressBar6,
                progressBar7,
                progressBar8,
                progressBar9,
                progressBar10,
                progressBar11
            };

        List<Task<bool>> taskList = new List<Task<bool>>();
        foreach (ProgressBar pBar in listOfProgressBars)
        {
            pBar.Value = 0;
            pBar.Minimum = 0;
            pBar.Maximum = 100;
        }

        int i = 11;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            ProgressBar thisProgressBar = listOfProgressBars[j - 1];
            var progress = new Progress<int>((int value) =>
            {
                UpdateProgressBar(thisProgressBar, value);
            });

            taskList.Add(InnerProcess(j, progress));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    }

    public void UpdateProgressBar(ProgressBar pBar, int value)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.EndInvoke(this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { UpdateProgressBar(pBar, value); })));
        }
        else
        {
            pBar.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public Task<bool> InnerProcess(int waitTime, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        return Task<bool>.Run(() =>
            {
                var job = new LongJob();
                job.Delay(waitTime, progress);
                return true;
            });
    }

    class LongJob
    {
        public void Delay(int i, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Report(j/i*100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, `Progress<T>` captures the current sync context when it is created and uses that to invoke the callback. It is necessary to used `InvokeRequired`/`BeginInvoke` here.

Answer (score 1):

```
progress.Report(j/i*100);
```

`j/i` is integer division, since j is less that i until completion, `j/i` is 0.

cast j to a float and all should be good

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your progress calculation due to integer division. Change it to this:

```
progress.Report((int)(((double)j) / i * 100));
```